# How to refresh parent page after modal dialog is closed?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have an ASP.NET page that contains an  tag which opens a modal dialog. This modal dialog contains a control that contains a button which saves some data and closes the modal dialog. How to refresh the parent page that button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this javascript line from the modal:

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

or

```
parent.location.reload();
```

If you do not have access to the modal, you can set a handler for the close as

```
ModalObject.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.top.location.reload();
};
```

where ModalObject is the handler that you have when you creates it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the modal dialog code (it's already in a dll). I guess that parent.location gives me the popup location not the parent page.

Comment: Didn't get that, do you have some links?